# Suche ein Wort, in Richtung: Periode, Zyklus, Progression, Staffel, Tagebuch usw.

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, single-word-request

Gibt es ein Wort, das folgenden Sachverhalt als Adjektiv beschreibt?

In meinem Blog behandle ich verschiedene Themen, die zu der umfangreichen Kategorie Webentwicklung gehören. Ich beschäftige mich über mehrere Wochen hinweg sehr intensiv mit einem expliziten Thema (z. B. Box2D in JavaScript). Der Wechsel zwischen den Themen ist unregelmäßig, die Themen an sich werden progressiv behandelt.

Ich suche ein Wort, das diesen Prozess treffend beschreibt.

Ich bin mir ziemlich sicher, dass es dafür ein einfaches Wort gibt, komme aber gerade partout nicht darauf.

Comment: Mir ist absolut nicht klar, worauf du genau hinauswillst. Inwiefern soll sich das Thema ändern? Sprichst du die Änderung des Hauptthemas an oder die Behandlung des Hauptthemas durch verschiedene Subthemen, die nach und nach ein Gesamtbild ergeben. Wie wäre es vllt mit Wörter fortwährend, fortlaufend, laufend, kontinuierlich, ...?

Comment: @Em1 ich habe (bzw will) ein Blog, dass sich mit Themen beschäftigt, die in die ziemlich große Kategorie "Web-Enwticklung" fallen. Ich beschäftige mich meist intensiver über ein paar Wochen hinweg mit einem explizitem Thema (zB Box2D in JavaScript) und würde das gerne zum Merkmal machen. Mir fehlt jedoch ein Wort wie Periodizität, da weniger nach Periodizität klingt. So klarer?

Comment: Dann denke ich an sowas: aktuell, aktiv, augenblicklich, derzeitig.

Comment: Oh, derzeitig find ich schonmal gut. Das kann ich gut als Label für das aktuelle Hauptthema benutzen. Danke! :D

Comment: Ich hab versucht deinen Kommentar in die Frage einfließen zu lassen. Lies das mal Korrektur und passe ggf. an, falls ich dich falls verstanden habe. Insbesondere den Satz "Ich suche ein Wort,..." ist glaube ich noch falsch, da du anscheinend - wie dein letzter Kommentar andeutet - eher nach einem Wort für *Aktualität* suchst.

Comment: Perfekt, vielen Dank! Naja, Aktualität impliziert als Leser zu sehr, dass es um aktuelle Themen geht - was nicht unbedingt der Fall sein muss.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ich würde [sporadisch](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/sporadisch) vorschlagen, auch, wenn es (in meinen Augen nur sehr) leicht negativ konnotiert ist, trifft es doch den Sachverhalt sehr genau. Analog zu [Periodikum](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodikum) wären Deine Artikel dann wohl ein Sporadikum... Oder langweilig: Eine [Schriftenreihe](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schriftenreihe).

Comment: Periodikum/Sporadikum finde ich sehr erfrischend! Kommen ganz weiter nach oben auf meiner Liste. Danke dafür :)

Answer (score 6):

Hier mein Vorschlag:

> In meinem Blog möchte ich ***in unregelmäßiger Folge*** verschiedene Themen zur Webentwicklung behandeln.

Natürlich geht dies nur, wenn die Themen tatsächlich unregelmäßig wechseln, wie Du schreibst. Sonst wäre *"in regelmäßiger Folge"* treffender.

Hier noch eine weitere Alternative

> In meinem Blog möchte ich ***nach und nach*** verschiedene Themen zur Webentwicklung behandeln.

Answer (score 3):

Da nicht jedes Thema gleich lange behandelt wird, ist die einzige Einschränkung, welche deskriptiv genutzt werden kann, dass jeweils nur ein Thema zu gegebenem Zeitpunkt behandelt wird, also die Themen einzelne Elemente in einer *Sequenz* darstellen. Daher mein Vorschlag:

> In meinem Blog möchte ich **sequenziell** verschiedene Themen zur Webentwicklung behandeln.

Answer (score 0):

"ein progressives Thematikum" ;-) Das würde m.E. auch einen leicht humorigen Einschlag haben. Eigentlich würde ich diese Art von blog als "Handbibliothek in Progression" bezeichnen, gglfs noch mit "unsystematisch" oder "Lieblingsthemen" erweitert - aber ich habe vielleicht einen zu "alten" Sprachstil (Ich stamme aus den 50'gern)

Answer (score 0):

Wie wär's mit

> abgeschlossene Reihen von Posts zu wechselnden Themen aus dem
>   umfangreichen Feld *Webentwicklung*